# Skip single failsafe integration test

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

For a specific build, I would like to run on the command line all the integration tests except one. I'm using maven-failsafe-plugin and I found you can run single IT with:

```
-Dit.test=ITCircle
```

(http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/single-test.html#)

Is it possible to exclude specific test on the command line? Something like

```
-Dit.test=!ITCircle
```

Thanks!